# Shiny application does not give an output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a shiny app mainly using navbarlist. But it does not give an output. I can't find where the fault is. Thank you in advance.

```
library(gridExtra)
shiny::runApp(list(
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "plotType", "Plot Type",
    c(All = "All",
      Cluster1 = "Cluster1",
      Cluster2 = "Cluster2")),

  navlistPanel("Cluster Summaries",
               tabPanel("All",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus")),
                                       column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Employee Code",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_emp_clus")),
                                                 column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_emp_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Marriage Years",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_myr_clus")),
                                                  column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_myr_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Years To Contract Expiry",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_yr_clus")),
                                                            column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_yr_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Age",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_age_clus")),
                                       column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_age_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Designation Code",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_deg_clus")),
                                                    column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_deg_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Gender",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_gen_clus")),
                                          column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_gen_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Housing Amount",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_ham_clus")),
                                                  column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_ham_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Living With",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_liv_clus")),
                                               column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_liv_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Number of children",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_chl_clus")),
                                                      column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_chl_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Overtime",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus")),
                                            column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Union Members",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus")),
                                                 column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Salary",fluidRow(column(1,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus")),
                                          column (2, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie"))))
               )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot_all_clus = renderPlotly({
    print(
      ggplotly(
        ggplot(gg, aes(x = V1 , y = V2))+
          geom_point())
    )
  })

}

))
```

here gg, gg1, gg2 are datasets. I even tried with normaly used datasets like mtcars. But it doesn't seem to give an output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please dont name outputs under the same name, all ids have to be unique. Also increase column size so the plots can fit in:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "plotType", "Plot Type",
    c(All = "All",
      Cluster1 = "Cluster1",
      Cluster2 = "Cluster2")),

  navlistPanel("Cluster Summaries",
               tabPanel("All",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus")),
                                       column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Employee Code",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_emp_clus")),
                                                 column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_emp_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Marriage Years",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_myr_clus")),
                                                  column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_myr_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Years To Contract Expiry",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_yr_clus")),
                                                            column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_yr_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Age",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_age_clus")),
                                       column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_age_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Designation Code",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_deg_clus")),
                                                    column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_deg_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Gender",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_gen_clus")),
                                          column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_gen_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Housing Amount",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_ham_clus")),
                                                  column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_ham_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Living With",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_liv_clus")),
                                               column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_liv_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Number of children",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_chl_clus")),
                                                      column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_chl_pie")))),

               tabPanel("Overtime",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus2")),
                                            column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie2")))),

               tabPanel("Union Members",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus3")),
                                                 column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie3")))),

               tabPanel("Salary",fluidRow(column(8,plotlyOutput("plot_all_clus4")),
                                          column (8, plotlyOutput("plot_all_pie4"))))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot_all_clus = renderPlotly({
    ggiris <- qplot(Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
    ggplotly(ggiris)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]